# log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4 logging error ResultSet.isClosed

Tags: oracle, log4j2, slf4j, java-6, log4jdbc

I am using log4j2, and I added "log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4" library to express the sql query statement log, but there is an error at runtime.

System Specifications:

1. jdk1.6
2. log4j2.3.2
3. slf4j-api 1.7.12

What I did:

- Add jar to maven

  org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2
        log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4
        1.16
- Change settings
- Add log4jdbc.log4j2.properties

  log4jdbc.spylogdelegator.name=net.sf.log4jdbc.log.slf4j.Slf4jSpyLogDelegator
  log4jdbc.dump.sql.maxlinelength=0
- Add logger to log4j2.xml

    (jdbc.resultset also causes an error when setting the level to DEBUG.)

The following error occurs when displaying the resultSet.

[image]

It worked normally for other small projects using the same DB!
I have no idea which part is causing the error.
I need help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was an error caused by the presence of both ojdbc6 and ojdbc14 in the development environment.